# View all files in folder structure (in Ubuntu or MacOS)

Tags: macos, ubuntu

Call I view all files in a folder structure (i.e., in all of the recursive daughter folders) in one window? Command line is good, too (I'm on Ubuntu or MacOS).

Scenario: I have a bunch of pdfs in directory, but I'd like to categorize them without losing the ability to easily browse all at once. I plan on using search, too, but it's nice to have the ability to see all of these pdfs in one list.

Comment: Thanks! All great answers! After submitting I realized an easy GUI way: Search for a wildcard in the top folder, which will show every pdf in the daughters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the command line, this might be helpful:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | less
```

In [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) (`mc`), Command > Find File > Filename *.pdf > check Find Recursively > OK > Panelize.

In Nautilus in Ubuntu just do a search for pdf and add the Location column to View > Visible Columns. You can further restrict the search by clicking on the plus sign and adding the additional criterion that the File Type should be PDF/Postscript.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, you could create a custom Smart Folder to do that for you.  Create it in finder to show you all PDFs.  Save it somewhere, then open that .savedSearch in a text editor (its just a simple XML file).

Near the bottom you'll see a key called `FXScopeArrayOfPaths`.  The value is an array, probably with just one `<string></string>` tag, that will be something along the lines of `kMDQueryScopeComputer`.  Change 'kMDQueryScopeComputer' to be the path to where ever you want the search rooted (`/Users/<username>/Documents/PDF Files`).

Answer (score 2):

The [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) command can do this. For example,

```
tree -F -A -C -P "*.pdf"
```

produces a nice structure like this:

```
. 
├── foo.pdf 
└── SomeDir/    
    ├── Bar.pdf*
    └── Baz.pdf
```

Unfortunately, this is a directory listing program, so folders that do not contain a PDF will still be listed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of all the files, including hidden files you can do the following command in the shell from the highest directory in the tree you want to consider:

```
% find .
```

If you want to see just the pdf's

```
% find . -name *.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Mac OS X Finder, set the view to the folder window to `as List`, and the <kbd>Option</kbd> click the small disclosure triangle next to the folder you want to view. This will open all the disclosure triangles of all sub-folders for you.

I find (On Mac OS X 10.5) that I sometimes have to close the disclosure triangle and kbd>Option click it again to get really deeply nested folders to open,i.e. if I need to see more than 3 or 4 levels deep.